# Appending "Hello" to beginning of each item in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a homework problem asking me to map over the names array, and return a new array with "Hello," appended to the beginning of each name.

The elements are changed when run for the problem.

I have to use an arrow function, and also the map method. I'm having trouble finding how to use both the map method, while making sure it adds "Hello," to each element in the array.

This is the code and what I have so far.

Any suggestions?

```js
var names = "TBD";

var formalGreeting = () => {
  names.map("Hello," + names)
};
```

So far this just adds the hello to the first element.

Comment: You're using the correct function but are not using it right. Refer to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Also, where's your array?

Comment: As in the new array? I don't believe it requires me to define one.

Comment: No, the original one. There's no array at all in your sample. `$names` is a string.

Comment: Oh i see what you're asking. The "TBD" string is changed when the test runs the code and changes it for an array. I dont have to mess with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var names = ['John', 'Max', 'Ellie'];
var namesWithGreeting = (arr) => {
    return arr.map(name => "Hello " + name);
}

namesWithGreeting(names);
//Output: ['Hello John', 'Hello Max', 'Hello Ellie']
```

You pass in an array to your function, and then use the map method to iterate over all the names, returning a new array with all names concatenated with "Hello ".

Comment: That totally makes sense. It must have something to do with how the test is run on the function and array which does not let that work. I'm trying to figure out a variation of that to get it to work.

Comment: var names = "TBD";

var formalGreeting = () => {
  //Your code here
}

This is what they provided me fully. I'm thinking they dont want me to put any parameters in for the function because it will do that when it runs the test. Makes testing difficult.

Comment: That seems strange. What you can do is use the `arguments` object in your function.
`var namesWithGreeting  = () => return arguments[0].map(el => "Hello " + el)`

Comment: I think i'm going to have to come back to this one at a later point. I've tried all the variations i can personally think of as well as trying all of the suggested options. I believe many of these are correct, but it has something to do with the input they're using. Super annoying. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This will work--

```
var a=["ashay","neeti"];
var e=(w)=>{return w.map(n=>"Hello "+n)};
alert(e(a));
```

Comment: They have some strange input that causes all of my own variations as well as any of these to not work. I have found they work outside when i determine the input however. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Finally got it!:

    var formalGreeting = () => {
    return names.map((names) => "Hello, "+names)
    }

Answer (score 0):

The `map()` method calls a provided callback function once **for each element** in an array, in order, and **constructs a new array** from the results.

So in the following code snippet, we are mapping the array `names` where each element in the array is `x` an for each element we return back the element with the string **`Hello,`** appended before it.

As mentioned above, the `map()` does not mutate the current array that is being mapped but **returns a new array** so all we have to do now is assign the new array that you got from mapping `names` to the variable `newNames`.

```js
var names = ["A", "B", "C"];

var formalGreeting = (array) => {
  var newNames = array.map(x => {
    return "Hello," + x;
  });
  console.log(newNames);
 };

formalGreeting(names);
```

Comment: This definitely works, but for some reason the inputs they use don't allow it to work. I'm still going to experiment with it. It's basically asking to have empty inputs everywhere and they fill out all of the inputs when the "test" is run.

Comment: "It's basically asking to have empty inputs everywhere and they fill out all of the inputs when the "test" is run." <-- I don't understand.

Comment: This was the final answer:
var formalGreeting = () => { return names.map((names) => "Hello, "+names) }